# To execute SQL query takes a lot of time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables. Tables 2 contains more recent records.
Table 1 has 900K records and Table 2 about the same.

To execute the query below takes about 10 mins. Most of the queries (at the time of execution the query below) to table 1 give timeout exception.

```
    DELETE T1
    FROM Table1 T1 WITH(NOLOCK)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 T2
    ON T1.ID = T2.ID
    WHERE T2.ID IS NULL AND T1.ID IS NOT NULL
```

Could someone help me to optimize the query above or write something more efficient?
Also how to fix the problem with time out issue?

Comment: Which database engine (SQL Server?)? What indexes exist on the tables?

Comment: SQL server. Do I need to add index on ID column in both tables?

Comment: why would "T1.ID IS NOT NULL" ever be false? it's on the LHS of the join

Comment: If you don't have an index, there will be roughly 900k x 900k operations.  There's no real way to optimize your query beyond that.

Comment: @Andrew - no it's just redundant.

Comment: @spinning_plate: SQL Server can do hash- and merge-joings, which would both do considerably better than 900k^2 in this case. And I think the query-optimizer should be able to correctly guess that a nested-loops-join is NOT the best way to execute this query.

Comment: @pgroke - I meant the query itself, as in, there's no way I saw to rewrite the query to make it more efficient.

Comment: @Andrew Venture: to be sure "delete rows on table1 that don't exist in table2"

Answer (score 1):

Optimizer will likely chose to block whole table as it is easier to do if it needs to delete that many rows. In the case like this I delete in chunks.

```
while(1 = 1)
begin
    with cte
    as
    (
        select *
        from Table1
        where Id not in (select Id from Table2)
    )
    delete top(1000) cte

    if @@rowcount = 0
        break

    waitfor delay '00:00:01' -- give it some rest :)
end
```

So the query deletes 1000 rows at a time. Optimizer will likely lock just a page to delete the rows, not whole table.

The total time of this query execution will be longer, but it will not block other callers.

Disclaimer: assumed MS SQL.

Another approach is to use `SNAPSHOT` transaction. This way table readers will not be blocked while rows are being deleted.

Comment: MS SQL is indeed a reasonable assumption for a question tagged with "tsql" ;)

Comment: Alex just want to confirm. Are you sure the select statement gives the same result as my query?

Comment: I have added indexes on both tables. Trying to execute your query. During the time it executes trying to select one record, gives timeout. Do you know what can be wrong?

Comment: @pgroke - not sure if you know but it is possible to edit questions. Question didn't have `sql-server` and `tsql` tags before.

Comment: @Andrew Venture - I assume that Id is not nullable. If so than one condition is redundant, like Mitch Wheat pointed out. Another condition will show only those rows that exists in Table1 and do not exist in Table2. So, yes I believe that my query is equivalent of your query, you can check it, right?

Comment: Id is not identity and can be null. The idea is delete all from table one which is not present in table 2 and ID is unique kind of idea for each record. But some of the records can be null

Comment: Add extra check to check if it is null, if you want to ignore null values

Comment: cannot execute the query all the time time outs if I query the table

Comment: @Andrew Venture - try to decrease row count.

Comment: @Andrew Venture - this a real query from my production cleanup job. It does not block whole table. You don't run the query in transaction, do you?

Comment: @Alex Aza: yes, it's possible to edit questions, and it's even possible to add tags to questions of other users AFAIK. Wasn't meant as a criticism though :)

Answer (score 0):

Wait a second, are you trying to do this...

```
DELETE Table1 WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM Table2)
```

?

If so, that's how I would write it.
You could also try to update the statistics on both tables. And of course indexes on Table1.ID and Table2.ID could speed things up considerably.

EDIT: If you're getting timeouts from the designer, increase the "Designer" timeout value in SSMS (default is 30 seconds). Tools -> Options -> Designers -> "Override connection string time-out value for table designer updates" -> enter reasonable number (in seconds).

Comment: I'm trying to add index in SSMS and all the time getting Lock request timeout period exceeded

Answer (score 0):

Both ID columns *need* an index

Then use simpler SQL

```
DELETE Table1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.ID)
```

Comment: I have tried to run your query it takes the same time. most of the queries in table 1 are giving timeout. I know I'm doing something wrong. it's a production database so it has a lot of queries

Comment: Yes I do have indexes on both tables

Comment: The problem is it's about 60K records will be deleted